# A previously working implementation of GCM now throwing an "Invalid_Sender" error

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I have a previously working implementation of an Android application using Google's GCM to push notifications to registered devices. All of a sudden none of our devices were getting notifications, so we attempted to register a new device but got an INVALID_SENDER error. Here is the LogCat output:

```
GCMRegistrar  | Registering app <myapp> <12 digit sender id>
IntentHandler | handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = INVALID_SENDER, unregistered = null
```

Most of the questions I've found here on SO regarding this error were fixed by using a correct project id as the sender id, but I've checked the [Google API Console page](https://code.google.com/apis/console) and the GCM for Android is turned on and the sender ID that the app is sending matches the project number (have had two other people verify this also just to be sure).

No Android code regarding GCM has changed (Nor the manifest xml).

Has anyone has anything similar happen? Has the GCM changed in some drastic way over the past 6 months?

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: This problem seems to have gone away after we cleaned out our notification database. Not sure what was the reason.